# Create React App switch between public folders when building

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I created an app using the Create React App tool and now I have to deploy it. However, I have a requirement that the same app be used by different customers, so I have to deploy two or more different versions of it.

The difference between each version today is just the favicon and the tile of the app (set in the `index.html`).

Is there a way to tell the CRA to use a different public folders for each build. For example, I would like to have a build script like this in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-customer-a": "react-scripts build --public-folder /public-a",
    "build-customer-b": "react-scripts build --public-folder /public-b"
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but I usually replace react-scripts with webpack and modifying the build directory location in webpack is pretty easy.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but will I have to eject my CRA app?

Comment: You can or you can build your webpack configuration from scratch. It might make it easier to make small changes like build location but personally I usually do create-react-app then remove react-scripts and place in my webpack config that I created because it includes other tweaks and optimizations that I like in my projects.